# Tell me the query to inner join three tables

Tags: mysql

I have Three tables

- table1 - `student`
- table2 - `teacher`
- table3 - `class`

one thing common among these three table is `class id`.

I want to display the columns by `classid='grade1'`.
**result** should be as `classid , studentid , teacherid, locid`.

ERROR is:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.teacherid, c.locid FROM student_master a INNER JOIN teacher_link b ON a.classid' at line 2

my query is

```
select  a.classid, a.studentid
b.teacherid,
c.locid
FROM student_master a
INNER JOIN teacher_link b
ON a.classid = b.teacherid
INNER jOIN class_master c
ON a.classid = c.locid

WHERE a.classid = 'grade1' ;
```

Comment: And the problem is? Are you getting an error? Is the data coming back wrong?

Comment: Your query is correct. What is the problem in that mention that.

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.teacherid, c.locid FROM student_master a INNER JOIN teacher_link b ON a.classid' at line 2

Comment: Show exact table schemas as a result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`. Your conditions in joins don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *one thing common among these three table is **class id***

If it's the case then your query most likely should look something like this

```
SELECT  a.classid, a.studentid, b.teacherid, c.locid
  FROM class_master c JOIN student_master a 
    ON c.classid = a.classid JOIN teacher_link b
    ON c.classid = b.classid 
 WHERE c.classid = 'grade1'
```

Comment: Yes, @RajeshPaul, but this isn't one.  Look at the second JOIN, sharing a line with an unrelated ON.

Comment: @DavidWallace The main problem was not the comma but join conditions. Take a closer look.

Comment: Ooh, I take it all back.  Well spotted.  I am going to have to remove my upvote on the other two answers; although it IS hard when a question contains two different bugs.

Comment: Hehe.  Just discovered that my upvotes are now locked in.  I guess the other two respondents each get a free pass!  But +1 for you too.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Take **a close look** at original join conditions `a.classid = b.teacherid` and `a.classid = c.locid`. They just don't make any sense.

Comment: Yes That's simply a logical mistake of the OP. But regarding the syntax error comma was the only reason. I agree.

Comment: @RajeshPaul My guess is OP wanted correct results, not just eliminate immediate syntax error and produce useless resultset (if it was at all possible)

Comment: The ironic thing is that in this particular query, the joins are a bit irrelevant, since `classid` is fixed in the `where` clause.  If you just fixed all three `classid` values in the `where` clause, and didn't include any join conditions at all, it would probably perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Error is missing comma(,) after `a.studentid`

So should be-

```
select  a.classid, a.studentid,
b.teacherid,
c.locid
```

Correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after a.studentid.

```
select  
    a.classid, a.studentid,b.teacherid,c.locid
FROM 
    student_master a
INNER JOIN 
    teacher_link b
ON 
    a.classid = b.teacherid
INNER jOIN 
    class_master c
ON 
    a.classid = c.locid
WHERE 
    a.classid = 'grade1' ;
```